Blazor: Using EventCallback with CascadingValue/CascadingParameter - is that possible?
I have a blazor application and I want to use EventCallback in my grandchild to call a function in my grandparent. The problem is, that the method in my grandparent never gets called.
I also use "normal" parameters to communicate from parent to child and in this case EventCallBack is working fine.
But doing it like this, it doesn't work:
This is the grandparent:
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<CascadingValue Value="IncrementCount" Name="SetCount">
    <Child/>
</CascadingValue>



@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}

This is the child:
<h3>Child</h3>

<p>I'm only existing to demonstrate something...'</p>

<Grandchild/>

@code {

}

And this the grandchild:
<h3>Grandchild</h3>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="HandleOnClick">Click me</button>

@code {

    [CascadingParameter(Name = "SetCount")]
    public EventCallback SetCount { get; set; }


    private void HandleOnClick()
    {
        SetCount.InvokeAsync();
    }
}


You could try followoing sample:
GrandChild.razor
<button @onclick="grandtest">test button</button>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback grandchildEvent { get; set; }

    private async Task grandtest()
    {
        await grandchildEvent.InvokeAsync();
    }
}

Child.razor
<GrandChild grandchildEvent="childEvent"></GrandChild>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback childEvent { get; set; }
}

Home.razor
@page "/"
<Child childEvent="test"></Child>
@display
@code{
    string display = "";
    private void test(){
        display = "Get called";
    }
}

Test result

------------------------------update----------------------
Using cascading parameter:
GrandChild.razor
<button @onclick="grandtest">test button</button>
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public Action grandchildEvent { get; set; }
    private async Task grandtest()
    {
        grandchildEvent.Invoke();
    }
}

Child.razor
<GrandChild></GrandChild>

Home.razor
@page "/"
<CascadingValue Value="test" >
    <Child ></Child>
</CascadingValue>
@display
@code {
    string display = "";
    public void test()
    {
        display = "Get called";
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}


Yes, this would work. As I mentioned, using only "normal" params and not CascadingParams/CascdadingValues it works fine. But in my application it would be very inefficient to do it that way...

@Dom Using Action would work. And don't forget statehaschange(). I have update the answer you could have a try.

You are nearly there.  You can't cascade an EventCallback, but you can cascade any delegate such as an Action or Func.
IncrementCounter fits the Action delegate, so you need to change your GrandChild as shown below.
<h3>Grandchild</h3>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="HandleOnClick">Click me</button>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "SetCount")] public Action? SetCount { get; set; }

    private void HandleOnClick()
    {
        SetCount?.Invoke();
    }

You also need to change IncrementCounter to add a call to StateHasChanged. This is needed because when called through the cascade, it's not invoked though the IHandleEvent hander and StateHasChanged is not called automatically.
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        // Only required when when called through the cascade but, 
        // as this is sync code, the component only renders once because 
        // the second call by the IHandleEvent hander [when triggered by the local button click] is ignored.
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }

